# Java - PriorityQueue: Does smaller value has high priority or bigger value do?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I wrote a simple program with `PriorityQueue`, but the output order by `poll()` is in reverse order as expected.

---

### Code

**PriorityQueueTest.java:** (*junit test*)

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PriorityQueueTest extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void testPriorityQueue() {

        int ids[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int priorities[] = { 5, 6, 5, 4, 7 };
        int outputIds[] = { 5, 2, 1, 3, 4 };

        PriorityQueue<PrioTask> pq = new PriorityQueue<PrioTask>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            pq.add(new PrioTask(ids[i], priorities[i]));
        }

        PrioTask task;
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            task = pq.poll();
            System.out.printf("%d, ", task.getId());
            // assertEquals(task.getId(), outputIds[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}

class PrioTask implements Comparable<PrioTask> {
    private int id;
    private int priority;

    public PrioTask(int id, int priority) {
        this.id = id;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PrioTask o) {
        return this.priority - o.priority;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

---

### **Output**

Expected output: `5, 2, 1, 3, 4,`

Actual output: `4, 1, 3, 2, 5,`

---

**The question is:**

- The task with higher priority should be polled first, right? Did I impl the `compareTo()` method wrong (priority property with bigger value has higher priority), or I understand `PriorityQueue` wrong?

---

### **@Update:**

I just added a test method for `Integer` values,

**test method for `Integer`:**

```
@Test
public void testInteger() {

    Integer values[] = { 5, 2, 1, 3, 4 };
    Integer outputValues[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        pq.add(values[i]);
    }

    Integer value;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        value = pq.poll();
        System.out.printf("%d, ", value);
        // TODO ... why the output is in reverse order as expected ?
        // assertEquals(task.getId(), outputIds[i]);
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");
}
```

The output is: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,`

**The additional question is:**

- It seems `PriorityQueue` will think the smaller value has high priority, is that so?

---

### @Summary

- `PriorityQueue` will think the smaller value has higher priority (small or big is decided by nature or `Comparable` interface).
- Retrieving from `PriorityQueue` via `poll()` or other methods should expect to receive the item with smaller value first.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator is back to front. It should be

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(PrioTask o) {
        return o.priority-this.priority;
    }
```

Answer to supplementary question, from the Javadoc:

> The *head* of this queue is the *least* element with respect to the specified ordering.

Comment: I did tried that, that would make the actual output same as expected. But, the java doc says `Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.` I think I wrote it correctly according to the java doc.

Comment: I updated the question with test for `Integer`, it seems the `compareTo()` is correct, but the `PriorityQueue` would take items with smaller value as high priority.

Comment: Off topic : Avoid subtraction logic in compare methods as integer operations can overflow to give wrong results; Eg Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE. Use relational operators instead.

Comment: In that case, I think I should modify the expectation, not the logic of `compareTo()` method. In order word, expect lower value has high priority, just like the `nice` value in linux process.

Comment: Thx for help, up voted for the `supplementary question` part, but can't accept as answer due to the `compareTo()` part to avoid misleading for future readers.

Comment: @EricWang Unless your priorities are going to approach Integer.MAX_VALUE this is a non-issue, and in any case the problem was present in your original code.

Comment: @EJP I know that part, what I mean in previous comment is that the `compareTo()` from your answer is wrong, my original logic for `compareTo()` is correct, the supplementary testing method using `Integer` in the question proved that. The mistake I made in the beginning is my expectation for `PriorityQueue` is wrong.